# Actualizar datos sin recargar página

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy extrayendo los datos de la api de twitter con Codebird, como puedo hacer para que salga el tweet mas reciente sin tener que actualizar la página? Tengo esto así:  pero la idea es que no se recargue la página?

Código Html:

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>twitter</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="codebird.js"></script>

    <META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="200;">

<style>
*{margin:0px;
    padding:0px;}
    
    #myVideo {
    position: relative;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%
    }
    #content-text {
    position: absolute;
    
    z-index:9999;
    font-size:47px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color:#9e9d9e;
    margin:0px 600px;
    margin-top:20px;
    top: 270px;
    left: 10px;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
    

<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
        <source src="horizontal.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div id="content-text"></div>

    

    <script>
    var cb = new Codebird;
    cb.setConsumerKey('pYz6237I1RQtX7AdyXwzuTPpd','bZGzPGMnE11dZ2Cdc0reDWMyQoLFdu3VLZm9W8FUy8xnVw7Qos');
    cb.setToken('1045064296714162176-aeOY3I2iKgymOzhWaXrbwQodctcfr5','Xs1aiRQ2RDwScUrm958qjHxy2p11aAGX4dsy2MrVBuIBL');

    var params = { 
    q: 'from:sttmed AND -filter:retweets AND -filter:replies',
    result_type: 'recent',
    count: 1

        
}; cb . __call ( "search_tweets" , params, function (reply) {
   // ... 
   document.getElementById('content-text').innerText = reply.statuses[0].text;
    

});

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Podrías usar .prepend() o .append() de query. En caso de no querer usar jquery tienes esta forma de añadir contenido: https://clubmate.fi/append-and-prepend-elements-with-pure-javascript/

Comment: Alguna otra solución ?

Comment: puedes usar un `setInterval` para ejecutar una y otra vez el mismo código o averiguar si CodeBird provee stream de datos